# How to disable log message of arsenic using chrome driver and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to disable all of just part of the log message that appear on the console, when I run the code.

There is a lot os message that it is not important to me.

I already tried the code below.

```
 # Install Cromedriver on the system
            self.service = services.Chromedriver(log_file=os.devnull,binary=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        
            args=['--headless', '--disable-gpu',"--log-level=3"]
            kwargs = {'goog:chromeOptions': dict(args=args)}
```

But the log level did not worked.